# How do I extract a word, that is contained in a group/list of words, from a string?

Tags: r, stringi

From a character vector of strings

```
x <- c("Point to Point Movement, Route/Network Building",                                                                       
       "Betting/Wagering, Dice Rolling, Roll / Spin and Move",
       "Hand Management, Take That")
```

extract a word if it is contained in

```
p <- c("Route","Dice")
```

otherwise `NA`. The resulting output would be "Route" from `x[1]`, "Dice" from `x[2]`, and `NA` from `x[3]`.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste the words as a single string and use that in `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, str_c(p, collapse="|"))
[1] "Route" "Dice"  NA
```

Comment: TY. This answer was so fast that I cannot even accept it yet.